# Avoid Duplicate Network Call Using Android-ViewModel (M-V-VM)

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

Assume there is an activity 'A'. Inside activity 'A' in `onCreate()` method you are initialising a ViewModel and after that making a network call using viewmodel like `vmInstance.getBooksFromSource()` inside `onCreate()` only. Now assume my network call  response has come, meanwhile user will rotate the screen and again activity 'A' `onCreate()` method will be triggered and we will get the same old viewmodel instance but once again my `vmInstance.getBooksFromSource()` will get triggered. So now I wanted to remove unnecessary call if I already got the response so don't hit the server again.

Right now I am maintaining a local boolean flag (by default its value is false) inside activity and enabling it if I am getting response from server and saving its value on `onSavedInstanceState()`. And then inside `onCreate()` method I am checking its value (checking through bundle) if its false then only I am making network call. Is there any other way to identify to avoid unnecessary network call if data already came from viewodel method that is `vmInstance.getBooksFromSource()`

Answer (score 4):

You can call your method inside the `init` of the `ViewModel`.

```
class YourViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    init {
        getBooksFromSource()  
    }
}
```

Your ViewModel will retain its instance after a configuration change and it won't be recreated. Place in the init block your method will prevent multiple calls to them, as it will only be called one time, once the ViewModel is created.

Comment: Yeah, That will work. But what if the same viewmodel is shared by multiple Activities then it will be unnecessary call for other activities .

Comment: If the requirements for the activities are different, you should split the logic of your ViewModel in two different ViewModels.

Comment: This works, however unable to unit test as it makes the call as soon i mock, any suggestion. ?

Answer (score 1):

```
livedata = Livedata<Object> //class member
getBooksFromSource(){
 if(livedata !=null){
   // call network 
}else{
  // do nothing.
}
return livedata
```

}

this will only call once if instance is null which is only for the first time.